# Standard deviation of multiple items whose standard deviation is known

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am asked the following question:

> The weights of apples from Tony’s farm follow a normal distribution with a mean of 158 g and a standard deviation of 13 g. The apples are sold in bags that contain six apples. Find the standard deviation of the weights of these bags of apples.

Seems easy enough (and wrong) to multiply the standard deviation by six and say that the standard deviation of the bag is 78g.

How should I go about solving it? I was not successful in finding anything online that would help me (probably for not knowing which terms to insert in the search). The mark scheme says that the variance is $6 \times 13^2$, which means that the standard deviation is $31.8$ rounded to three significant figures. I just want to understand where that comes from.

Comment: Variance is additive here.  Standard deviation is not.

Comment: When two random variables are uncorrelated you add the variances. When they are perfectly correlated, you add the standard deviations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpret the problem statement as follows: let $(W_i)_{i=1}^6$ be independent, normally distributed random variables with mean $158$ and *variance* $13^2$. Since $W_i$ are independent and identically distributed:
$$Var(\sum_{i=1}^6 W_i) = \sum_{i=1}^6 Var(W_i) = 6 Var(W_1) = 6 \times 13^2.$$

Note that if you try and replace variance with standard deviation, the first equality fails. The variance of the sum of independent random variables is the sum of their variances, and this follows from the definition of variance. The standard deviation does not have this property.

Comment: (1) In first two terms, $i$ is the index. In the third term , what is $i$ ? (2) Instead of $Var()$ , what if I had used $SD()$ & done the exact same chain ?

Comment: @Prem sloppy notation, I meant just pick any one of the indices for $i$. If you had picked standard deviation, the first equality would fail to hold. It is a fact that follows from the definition of variance that if random variables are independent then the variance of the sum is equal to the sum of variances

Comment: (1) Either we can skip the $i$ & say that the 6 variables have the same variance $W$ , totaling to $6W$ Or we can say that each indexed variance is equal to $W$ , still totaling to $6W$. (2) the facts about adding $VAR()$ [ but not $SD()$ ] should be included in your Answer to make it complete.

Comment: @Prem (1) is not quite true, when we talk about random variables there are subtleties. If we say that each $W_i$ is equal on the nose to $W$, what that would mean is that they are just six copies of the same random variable, and so would not be independent. Also, $Var(6W) \neq 6 Var(W)$

Comment: @Prem (2) good idea, I will add that

Comment: I am not saying the variables are the same , I am saying Either "the variances are the same , equal to $W$" Or "the indexed variables have indexed variances which are all the same , equal to $W$".